# Simplify a series whose terms are defined as an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Consider this series $I_n$:

$$I_n = \int\limits_0^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n}(x)\ dx$$

How do I use *Mathematica* to simplify $I_n + I_{n+1}$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: Mathematica input should be provided, images do not cut and paste very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually it is convenient to use `Assumptions`, e.g.

```
Int[n_] = Integrate[Tan[t]^(2 n), {t, 0, Pi/4}, Assumptions -> n >= 0]
```

> ```
> 1/4 (-PolyGamma[0, 1/4 + n/2] + PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2])
> ```

The result is immediate, because

```
FullSimplify[1/4 (-PolyGamma[0, 1/4 + n/2] + PolyGamma[0, 5/4 + n/2])]
```

> ```
> 1/(1 + 2 n)
> ```

i.e.

```
FullSimplify[ Int[n] + Int[n + 1]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\frac{1}{2 n+1}$$

Comment: It is sufficient to assume `n>=0`, i.e., `n` need not necessarily be an integer.

Comment: @BobHanlon  Right.

Comment: Thanks ! Now, I need to show that In - I(n+1) <= 0. I use FullSimplify[Int[n] - Int[n + 1] >= 0] // TraditionalForm                           and I was expected a "True". But, nothing happens. Do you know why?

Comment: @nolw38 If you have another question, a good custom is asking it as a separate one. I would demonstrate  in details how to prove it, however since you've neither upvoted  nor accepted my answer I'll only suggest to look at the formula $5.9.16$ in [NIST](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9) and use a simple inequality between arithmetic and geometric means.

Comment: Sorry, just accepted your answer !!